# Redirect to appstore for app update objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile-application

I want to redirect to appstore for application update. From my application, i am able to redirect to appstore, but there is "Open" button instead of "Update".

I have used following code for appstore redirect for app update.

```
NSString *iTunesLink = @"itms://itunes.apple.com/np/app/appname/id123456789?mt=8"; 

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
```

Have i missed the procedure? Thank you.

Comment: may be the appstore is showing the old version of your app.

Comment: it is showing the new version with updated snapshots, descriptions and version number.

Comment: Do you already have a new version installed? Did you install the new version using the Xcode?

Comment: Look at this component [iRate](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate) I think you find useful info and will change your link

Comment: I have the old version in my device and trying to update application by redirecting to appstore from the application.

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: @RamGrg I am using this snippet for redirecting to appstore but i am getting this error -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/NAMEABC/myAppIDXYZ" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme itms-apps"

Comment: @Raviteja_DevObal please do try by setting NSAppTransportSecurity to YES for NSAppTransportSecurity key in plist. This issue also shows up if  LSApplicationQueriesSchemes key is missing in plist. Either can be a case, i guess.

Comment: @RamGrg Thanks for your suggestion .I already did it . I change my code as follow if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]]) { [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];         }